# How to get the result of an insert query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get the result of an insert query like this :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO articles (Title,Description) VALUES ('{$title}','{$description}')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

When I insert this `article` , I want his `ID` to use it in an other table ! the `$result` gives a `true` or `false` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ID of the inserted row by calling the function [mysqli_insert_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) directly after your `mysqli_query()`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO articles (Title,Description) VALUES ('{$title}','{$description}')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysqli_insert_id ()

```
$insertId = mysqli_insert_id ( $connection );
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this it return the value of your table fiele which is (peimary key) in this table

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```